# How to know if a view was inflated from an resource file (xml) in Android?

Tags: android

I have this method:

```
@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View inflated = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_lunch_view, parent, false);

    return new ItemViewHolder(inflated);
}
```

is there some way to do this?

```
ItemViewHolder holder = onCreateViewHolder();

if(holder.itemView.inflatedFrom(R.layout.item_lunch_view)){
    Log.i("stackoverflow", "Yes, this view was builded from R.layout.item_lunch_view");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You should rethink your problem. Here are some solutions that come to mind:

1. Set the tag of the view holder to the id of the parent view plus some unique id suffix so that you can still distinguish between multiple items. Since the tag can be anything why not that?
2. If you have multiple parent xmls, define a different id format for the child views in each one, so that by looking at the id of a child you can tell which one is parent. For example

   Parent

   Child android:id="+@id/parent1_view1"

   Child android:id="+@id/parent1_view2"

   /Parent

   ---

   Parent

   Child android:id="+@id/parent2_view1"

   Child android:id="+@id/parent2_view2"

   /Parent